# Laravel - Dynamic binding not working in one-to-many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My models are 
Employee, which has the relationship:

```
public function company(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company','company');
    }
```

and Company, which has the relationship:

```
public function employees(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Employee','company');
    }
```

`company` is the FK in my `employees` table, pointing to the `id` in my `companies` table. 
In tinker I run the following commands:

```
$employee = App\Employee::firstOrFail(); 
$employee->company; //returns 1
```

But when I do

```
$employee->company->name;
```

OR

```
$employee->company->id;
```

It returns the error:

```
PHP error:  Trying to get property of non-object on line 1
```

Comment: I think its because you have a column called `company` and your relation has exactly the same name, the column is a property of `$employee` thats why it returns `1` instead of an object.

Comment: if you `dd($employee->company)`, does it return an array or just `1`?

Comment: I think it is `App\Employee::firstOrFail()`. Is it a typo?

Comment: @AndyHolmes, just 1.

Comment: @Neat, make that an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Neat, the reason was that the fields were named the same as the relationship methods. 
I renamed the field `company` to `company_id` and it works fine now.